# Class or function to make a listview like table in html through php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, listview

i'm using PHP and jQuery for my website and i'm looking for a class or function that could translate an array or the result of fetches in a listview-like table.

With resizables columns, customizable colors, etc .. nothing really complicated

I could make one but i'm quite sure it already exists

Do you have such examples ?

Thanks

---

Sorry i thought jqGrid was not opensource but it seems it is ..
it seems to be the most updated Grid

do you agree ? have you got good experience of jqgrid ?

Thanks

Comment: yes, i have found some but i would like an opensource one, not like jqGrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqGrid is the great tool for what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that there is something that can do this in php, but I think you would probably just want to print a regular table and have JS do all the colorizing, sorting, etc.  Check out [jquery Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/).  I've had good luck with it.  You can handle the styling through CSS.